# Moving classes back into a project

Tags: xcode, xcode7

By mistake I created two classes outside of the main group, so I have my `.xcodeproj` together with this two classes. How can I move these two classes to be back into the project? The app is working.

Comment: Move them whenever you want on filesystem, delete them from your project (remove references) and then add them again (add files to...).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

1. Close Xcode
2. open your project in finder
3. move the classes to the correct place
4. Open Xcode
5. There will be question Marks in the classes you just moved
6. select the each class in project navigator
7. Right Click > Source Control > Add files > add StoryboardFiles to project
8. The question marks will turn A
9. Product > Clean
10. Run your app

When I had this problem in Xcode 7 it was not necessary to touch the references. Hope this helps